# How to copy with BitBlt?

Tags: winapi

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to copy certain colors from one dc to another ? What i have is a bitmap that contains a drawing and I want to copy everything except the white background color using the BitBlt. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you need [`TransparentBlt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. It is similar to `StretchBlt`, which in turn offers a superior functionality to `BitBlt`.

The function takes additional argument:

> crTransparent [in]
>
> The RGB color in the source bitmap to treat as transparent.